# regularization of $\hat{x} = \arg\min_x|Ax - b|^2 + \lambda|x|^2$ using SVD of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, svd, regularization

Suppose that the following energy is provided
$$
\hat{x} = \arg\min_x|Ax - b|^2 + \lambda|x|^2
$$
with a given matrix $A$, a vector $b$ and regularization paramter $\lambda$. Analyze how the solution of this minimization problem varies with $\lambda$ by using the singural value decomposition of $A$

by taking the gradient with respect to $x$ of the energy and by setting the gradient to zero, we obtain
$$
A^\top(Ax - b) + \lambda x = 0
$$
Finally we obtain 
$$
x = (A^\top A + \lambda I_d)^{-1}A^\top b
$$
Let us decompose $A$ via the SVD. Then, we obtain
$$
A = USV^\top
$$
where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $S$ is diagonal and with nonnegative entries. Then, we obtain
$$
x = V(S^2 + \lambda I_d)^{-1}SU^\top b = V\text{diag}\Big\{\frac{s_i}{s_i^2 + \lambda}\Big\}_{i = 1,..., n}U^\top b
$$
However if I plug in $A = USV^\top$ in $x = (A^\top A + \lambda I_d)^{-1}A^\top b$, I get
\begin{align*}
 x&= (A^\top A + \lambda I_d)^{-1}A^\top b\\
  &= ((USV^\top)^\top USV^\top + \lambda I_d)^{-1}(USV^\top)^\top b\\
  &= (VSU^\top USV^\top + \lambda I_d)^{-1}VSU^\top b\\
  &= (VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d)^{-1}VSU^\top b\\
\end{align*}
and I'm stuck to that point. Is it wrong? Which further steps are needed?

Comment: your final line $(VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d)^{-1}VSU^\top b$ does$ = V\text{diag}\Big\{\frac{s_i}{s_i^2 + \lambda}\Big\}_{i = 1,..., n}U^\top b$ after simplification, but I didn't think that was what was meant by the problem.  My read was don't take the gradient, instead consider the simpler problem of $\min:\big \Vert \Sigma \mathbf y - \mathbf c\big \Vert_2^2 + \lambda \big \Vert  y \big \Vert_2$  where $\mathbf c = U^T \mathbf b$ and $\mathbf y = V^T \mathbf x$.  The 2 norm is orthogonally inviariant over reals and if you work through this, it turns into a scalar calculus problem at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @user8675309. My question was precisely how you prove that $(VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d)^{-1}VSU^\top b = V\text{diag}\Big\{\frac{s_i}{s_i^2 + \lambda}\Big\}_{i = 1,..., n}U^\top b$  step by step. I tried (hence the attempt) but then got stuck

Comment: I'm going to drop $U^Tb$ since it isn't needed.  This really is basic diagonalization.  $(VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d) = VDV^{T} $ for othogonal V so  its inverse is $VD^{-1}V^T$ and $VD^{-1}V^TV S = VD^{-1} S =  V\text{diag}\Big\{\frac{s_i}{s_i^2 + \lambda}\Big\}_{i = 1,..., n}$ all you need to do is carefully evaluate diagonal matrix $D$ and its inverse

Comment: :n):n):n):n):n):n):n)!!!!!!!! @user8675309. Many thanks!!! (if you want to copy paste your comment in an answer, I'll be glad to upvote it and accept it)

Comment: One last question @user8675309. What I understand is that $S^2 + \lambda I_d = D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Now how can I be sure that $VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d = VFV^\top$. In other words, how can I prove that $VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d = V(S^2 + \lambda I_d)V^\top$

Comment: two way (1) $VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d = VS^2V^\top + V \lambda I_d V^T = V\big(S^2V^\top +  \lambda I_d V^T\big) = V\big(S^2 + \lambda I_d\big)V^\top$ -- idea: the (scaled) identity matrix 'shifts' eigenvalues.  (2) for *any* matrix $B$, if $B\mathbf v = \gamma \mathbf v$, then $(B+\lambda I) \mathbf v = B \mathbf v+\lambda I \mathbf v = \gamma \mathbf v + \lambda \mathbf v = \big(\gamma + \lambda\big) \mathbf v$.  now select $B:= VS^2 V^T$ .  You can apply this argument to each eigenvector and you know there are n linearly independent ones.  In both cases -- just carefully apply linearity.

Comment: Ok @user8675309. then from (1), what is not clear to me is why $\lambda I_d = V\lambda I_d V^\top$ (which is I believe assumed). I'm conscious of the fact that I asked much more than I should. If you don't want to answer anymore or don't have time, that's fine I understand, I can post another seperate question

Comment: @user8675309. I found the answer to my questions : $I =VV^\top = VIV^\top \implies \lambda I = V\lambda IV^\top$ (I now this really basic) but, not having a math background, it helps me working everything step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*final comment adapted as the answer:*
one thing to observe is that the (scaled) identity matrix is similar to itself, so $\lambda I = V (\lambda I) V^{-1}$

I dropped the term $U^T b$ since it isn't needed. This really is working through diagonalization.

$(VS^2V^\top + \lambda I_d) = VDV^{T}$ for othogonal $V$ so its inverse is $VD^{-1}V^T$  and we have $VD^{-1}V^TV S = VD^{-1} S =  V\text{diag}\Big\{\frac{s_i}{s_i^2 + \lambda}\Big\}_{i = 1,..., n}$.
All that needs to be done is to carefully evaluate diagonal matrix  and its inverse.